# What is the proper way to style Flutter RaisedButton?

Tags: flutter

Currently I am styling it using

```
MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
       buttonColor: Colors.blueAccent,
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20) ),
       textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary
    )
  )
)
```

But it is insane to assume that there is only one style apply to all buttons in the entire apps.

Currently I have 4 type of styles which to apply to `RaisedButton`, and can't figure out a good way of doing so. It is also a bit of hassle to subclass `RaisedButton` for each and every styles.

Comment: you can have multiple `Theme`s in your app, not only the one defined in `MaterialApp` - `Theme` is an ordinary `Widget`

Comment: @pskink how can I apply different Theme to RaiseButton?

Comment: place a `Theme` widget as the direct or indirect parent of `RaisedButton` widget (btw `RaisedButton` docs say: "This class is obsolete, please use ElevatedButton instead.")

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parameters for RaisedButton

```
 RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            textColor: Colors.white,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: <Color>[
                    Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                    Color(0xFF1976D2),
                    Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child:
                  const Text('Gradient Button', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
            ),
          ),
```